# Acer Aspire 5 Won't Resume from Sleep

Tags: 18.04, suspend, acer, aspire

My Acer Aspire 5 A515-43-R19L (Ryzen 3) running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS won't wake up after it goes to sleep. My keyboard lights up when I hit a key to try to wake it up, but nothing further happens and after a few seconds, the light goes back out. I have to hold down the power button to reboot whenever it goes to sleep.

I'm not very experienced with Linux, but have been trying to learn. I have not had much luck searching for answers to this question online. Also, it appears that enabling hibernate is not an alternative option due to issues with Secure Boot (and I'm unclear of the risks with disabling it, but perhaps this an option).

Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Installing AMD's Adrenaline driver worked! I booted into Windows 10 (sleeping has worked perfectly fine in Windows, so I was skeptical), downloaded and installed, and rebooted. Then rebooted into Ubuntu and now it works, I had tried everything and had given up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue with my new Acer A515-43-R19L on Windows 10 Pro. The laptop reboots on wake.

Installing AMD's Adrenaline driver fixed the issue.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you besides this is everything working? esp battery? are u on ubuntu 18 still or tried 20? my acer aspire e5 laptop battery life has gone down 40% after fresh install of 20.04. I assumed its hardware issue until read about another person having same issue on reddit

Comment: There is a BIOS update on Acer's website, updating the BIOS from 1.06 to 1.08.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my machine, which is the same system but with an I5-10210U. The problem started when I set up dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04.

What worked for me is resetting the BIOS configs. Boot into the BIOS and press F9 to load the default configs. After you do this, you need to change the SATA Mode to AHCI in order for Ubuntu to boot.

This fixed it. Hope this helps!